# Average of metrics using 10-fold

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, metric

I'm working with 10 k-fold cross validation and I'm wanting to average the metrics, but I'm not getting it with sklearn. This is the way I am doing it and the metrics are being printed by fold.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold 
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, f1_score, recall_score
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support as score


k = 10
kf = KFold(n_splits=k, random_state=None)
model = clf
 
    
for train_index , test_index in kf.split(x_train):
    x_train , x_test = X.iloc[train_index,:],X.iloc[test_index,:]
    y_train , y_test = Y[train_index] , Y[test_index]
     
    model.fit(x_train,y_train)
    pred_values = model.predict(x_test)
    
    
    precision, recall, fscore, support = score(pred_values, y_test)
    print('precision: {}'.format(precision))
    print('recall: {}'.format(recall))
    print('fscore: {}'.format(fscore))
    print('support: {}'.format(support))
```

Answer (score 0):

From the info you provide, I think you can do:

- average the test scores you get from your splits instead of printing per split, or
- use the cross_validation_score option given by sklearn, and then average such scores: cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=5).mean(), or
- use the sklearn GridSearchCV class, with which you can access the details of your cross validation strategy vía the cv_results_ parameter:
  http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html

You can see a related question and answer on:
[KFold cross validation ambiguity](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/92532/kfold-cross-validation-ambiguity/92535#92535)